# Compound indices for OR+Sort query in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

For this OR query:

```
db.messages.find({ $or: [ { to: { $ne: null }, from: "xyz" }, { to: "xyz" } ] }).sort({_id: -1}).limit(50)
```

with following indices:

```
{to:1, from: 1, _id:-1} and {from:1, to:1, _id:-1}
```

mongo is always doing a full scan.

I was hoping that mongo could use these two indices and merge the results.

Do I need to split this into two queries (one for each OR clause) and merge myself? Or is there some other index that can help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known issue, https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1205, which you can vote for if it is very important for your use case.

Comment: Glad I found this. Spent a few hours today thinking I was doing something dumb.