# Mongodb. Or and indexes

Tags: mongodb

I've noticed Mongodb 2.2 doesn't seem to use indexes if you use an OR operator as well as a SORT operator. I wonder if this [JIRA](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1205) is related to it.

Let me explain:

```
db.messages.ensureIndex({ 'to_id':1, 'sent_date':-1});
db.messages.ensureIndex({ 'from_id':1, 'sent_date':-1});
```

Ok we have indexes on the messages collection.

```
 db.messages.find( {$or: [{'to_id':ObjectId("5124c7a1afaf46ffbd90b470")}]} ).sort({'sent_date':-1}).explain()
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor to_id_1_sent_date_-1",

db.messages.find( {$or: [{'from_id':ObjectId("5124c7a1afaf46ffbd90b470")}]} ).sort({'sent_date':-1}).explain()
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor from_id_1_sent_date_-1",
```

OK so querying and then sorting by sent_date use a BtreeCursor.

```
db.messages.find( {$or: [{'to_id':ObjectId("5124c7a1afaf46ffbd90b470")}, {'from_id':ObjectId("5124c7a1afaf46ffbd90b470")}]} ).explain()
{
    "clauses" : [
        {
            "cursor" : "BtreeCursor to_id_1",
```

Ok a query with to_id OR from_id also uses a BtreeCursor.

```
db.messages.find( {$or: [{'to_id':ObjectId("5124c7a1afaf46ffbd90b470")}, {'from_id':ObjectId("5124c7a1afaf46ffbd90b470")}]} ).sort({'sent_date':-1}).explain()
{
    "cursor" : "BasicCursor",
```

FAIL! a query with to_id OR from_id AND a sort **does not use the index**. Why?

My questions:

- Has it always been like this?
- What do people do get round this - Do people perform 2 separate queries and glue the results together in code?

Comment: It is the sort not using an index, the $or is, yes it has always been like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6733468/compound-indices-for-orsort-query-in-mongodb ( https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1205 ) I believe that is what your hitting into

Comment: Yes, you'll need to do 2 queries and merge the sorted lists locally until it's resolved (planned for 2.6).

Comment: As I look again, actually reading this time around, I see you already found the JIRA